# Cleaning Mold From Fabrics, including Seats and Headliner

Tags: cleaning, interior, smell, water-leak

I own a Vauxhall Corsa Twinport (04) which previously leaked water through the bulkhead into the car, which results in pools of water in all footwell, plus significant damp across all fabrics. I fixed the leak by removing the old sealant around the bulkhead and stripped the inside down back to the metal to dry the car out completely. In this process, I took the opportunity to clean all the seats and fabrics including the carpet which I had removed as well.

However, I now am facing the problem of mold and the associated smell of mildew which has covered my seats and is starting to appear on the headliner, including the sun visors. I have researched cleaning products but cannot find anything that specifically deals with mold.

What are the best solutions to deal with both the mold and smell that now inhabit my car?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If mold is appearing on the headliner, I believe you will find that the humidity level inside the vehicle is still very high.  If you are in a location where the outside humidity is low you could open the windows and let it air out for a few hours and see if that helps.  Otherwise you may need to employ a dehumidifier to extract the excess moisture to get that under control.